# Parallel Pinging Hosts And Displaying Live Results

Tags: c#

I stumble on the following problems:

- When trying to use the Parallel Function. I need to synchronously wait until the all the information is gathered.
- When I put the foreach loop inside the try there are duplicate values.

How can I fix this? I want when I scan a subnet (254 hosts) that I get live results back.

**Code:**

```
//Network Information Parallel.ForEach Example
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;

namespace AsteRScanneR
{
    public class Program1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter IP Adresses seperated by a comma!");
            Console.Write("Enter IP Adresses: ");
            List<string> ipAdresses = new List<string>();
               ipAdresses = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();
            var firstOrDefault = ipAdresses.FirstOrDefault(); 
            string[] octets = firstOrDefault.Split('.');
            if (octets[3] == string.Empty)
            {
                ipAdresses = new List<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    var result = String.Concat(firstOrDefault, i.ToString());
                    ipAdresses.Add(result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Multiple IP's Found!");
            }


            //In case you want to scan a whole subnet, user needs to input only the ABC of the IP adres and leave the D empty. It will scan 255 hosts


            //Options
            PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);
            int timeout = 1000;
            string data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            List<PingReply> pingRepliesList = new();
            Parallel.ForEach(ipAdresses, ip =>
            {
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount, CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None };
                try
                {
                    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
                    sw.Start();
                    Ping p = new();
                    lock (pingRepliesList) { 
                    pingRepliesList.Add(p.Send(ip, timeout, buffer, pingOptions));
                    }
                    sw.Stop();
                    //Console.WriteLine("Pinging: "+ip+" took: "+sw.Elapsed.Milliseconds+"ms on Thread:"+ Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
                }catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An Error Occured...");
                }
                
            });
            Console.WriteLine("");
            foreach (var pingvalue in pingRepliesList)
            {
                if (pingvalue.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pinging " + pingvalue.Address.ToString() + " with " + pingvalue.Buffer.Length + " bytes of data:");
                    Console.WriteLine("Reply from " + pingvalue.Address.ToString() + ": bytes=" + pingvalue.Buffer.Length + " time" + pingvalue.RoundtripTime + "ms TTL=" + pingvalue.Options.Ttl);
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pinging " + pingvalue.Address.ToString() + " with " + pingvalue.Buffer.Length + " bytes of data:");
                    Console.WriteLine("General failure.");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A ping normally sends multiple ARPs for each IP address.  Normally you wait a max time period or when all the pings get returned which ever occurs first.  I would use the Async Ping instead of sending in parallel.  Then you can capture the Event(s) instead of looping.

Comment: @jdweng if you have an example for me, please do show. I am looking for an async approach where I can execute multiple Pings at once and then async waiting for one of the results to come so I can display them live.

Comment: See msdn example : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync?force_isolation=true&view=net-6.0

Comment: @jdweng this is of a single ping. I want to do multiple pings in parallel/async and then get the results when a task is completed.

Comment: Add a for loop around pingSender.SendAsync() to send multiple pin messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. This is what I did:

1. Used the example code from: https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/3279/parallel-for
2. Replacing the hard-coded list with for now the user-input. (This will be changed to args user input afterwards.)
3. Included the piece of code I wrote down below

```
            Console.WriteLine("Enter IP Adresses seperated by a comma!");
            Console.Write("Enter IP Adresses: ");
            List<string> ipAdresses = new List<string>();
            ipAdresses = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList();
            var firstOrDefault = ipAdresses.FirstOrDefault();
            string[] octets = firstOrDefault.Split('.');
            if (octets[3] == string.Empty)
            {
                ipAdresses = new List<String>();
                for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    var result = String.Concat(firstOrDefault, i.ToString());
                    ipAdresses.Add(result);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Multiple IP's Found!");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
```

4. Changed Parallel.For loop to .Count, because I am using a List
5. Changed some output result.Address.ToString() to ipAdresses[i] because it was creating bugs and displaying the same output over and over again.
6. Formatted everything in 1 string to not stumble upon problems.

I did format in 1 string on purpose, because when I formatted two strings I to get output mixed.

Comment: Hej there! Glad that you've found a solution to your problem. Perhaps you want to accept your answer, so that others with similar questions might find your answer more quickly.

Comment: @tophcito I have to wait 5 hours to do that, StackOverflow is a bit iffy on that. :) Will do when that timeout is done.